# Get data with the highest row length, MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, select

I'm trying to select the top 20 rows from a MYSQL table (I'm very new to MYSQL and I'm not even sure if it can be called a table). I have a few more conditions which I was able to meet by using inner join, not between etc. After all the processing, I have a table like below

```
name,h1,h2,h3
a   , 2, 4, 5
b   ,  ,54, 5
c   ,65, 7, 8
d   , 6,  , 3
e   , 7,  ,
f   ,-1, 3,-5
```

',,' indicates there's no data for that combination. I prefer having something like 'NA' there
The main thing is, I want to select the top 20 rows with highest length. By length I mean

```
name,length

a,3
b,2
c,3
d,2
e,1
f,3
```

I don't need the above table, but based on the length, I need the top 20 rows. I could do it using R but the table is really huge and I'd like to process it in MYSQL and then export the table to my computer. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want NA for the columns with no values, you can use IFNULL(col, 'NA')

```
select name , h1,h2,h3 
from table 
order by   LENGTH(CONCAT(h1,h2,h3))  desc
limit 20
```

Comment: Need to add order by on length with limit clause

Answer (score 0):

If I understand "length" correctly, you mean the number of non-NUL values.  If so, you can calculate this as:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (h1 is not null) + (h2 is not null) + (h3 is not null) desc
limit 20;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions integers, with true being 1 and false being 0.  So, the expression in the `order by` counts the number of non-NULL values.  It then orders the result in descending order and chooses the 20 rows with the most non-NULL values.